# JavaScript Array into Dictionary mapping not working properly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I want to map the java script array into dictionary:

```
let myArray=['first','second','third'];
```

**Expected Output**

```
result={first:1,second:1,third:1}
```

**Actual Output**

```
result=[{element:1}, {element:1}, {element:1}]
```

**Code:**

```
let myArray=['first','second','third'];

let result=myArray.map(element=>{

    return {element:1}

})
```

Comment: return {[element]:1}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this with `Object.assign` and spread syntax.

```js
let myArray=['first','second','third'];
let obj = Object.assign({}, ...myArray.map(key => ({[key]: 1})));
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: I usually use a reducer for this, but I like this method. Kudos.

Answer (score 2):

```js
let myArray=['first','second','third'];

let result = myArray.reduce((agg, ele) => {
   agg[ele] = 1;
   return agg;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: My requirement is little bit different @Nenad Vracar answer is right

Comment: Sorry for the confusion :)

Comment: Not that's not matter. I will appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 2):

```
   let myArray=['first','second','third'];

   let result=myArray.reduce((obj, element)=>{ 

    return {...obj, [element]:1}
 }, {})
```

A reducer will incrementally append your new key. The array key syntax uses the value of element as the new key

Comment: Fixed it.  I'd misunderstood the complete problem.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just a regular for loop?

```
  const result = {};
  for(const key of myArray)
    result[key] = 1;
```

Comment: +1 for                                                                                                           
                                 simplicity! (Also, efficiency).

Comment: You are right. But my purpose is little bit different. I post the part of the question. I did not post my real problem.

Comment: @sunny what? why are you asking a question if you don't need it?